# Extract data from Mysql::Object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql

I have code to run sql query in ruby as follows

> sql =
>   ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
>   sql.begin_db_transaction
>   report = sql.execute("select * from users;")
>   sql.commit_db_transaction

So after this report is an Mysql::object. Now I want to extract all fields and its corresponding data to array or hash.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute` method should produce a result which gives you a method called `all_hashes` - it will return an array of hashes corresponding to the rows of query's results, which seems to be what you need. So, call

```
report.all_hashes
```